# Update an image column using a variable

Tags: sql, image, sql-server-2008

I need to copy a value of an image column from one row to another. I tried to use variables for that, but I can't even declare that type of variable. SQL Server returned this error message:

> Msg 2739, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables.

Comment: Why are you still using `image` instead of `varbinary(max)`?

Comment: Not because of technical reasons. It's a legacy project and now customer pays only for support. So our managers decided, that database strucure and source code of app must still unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the `image` data type has been deprecated, so you should be changing your tables and all of your code to use `varbinary(max)` (you will *have* to do this at some point, the sooner the better). An easy workaround in the meantime would be to use `varbinary(max)` in your variable:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(i IMAGE);

INSERT @x SELECT 0x0045;

DECLARE @y VARBINARY(MAX);

SELECT @y = i FROM @x;

PRINT @y;

-- UPDATE sometable SET somecolumn = @y WHERE ...;
```

However if you are performing an update, why do you need to use an intermediate variable in the first place? You can join two rows in the same table quite easily...

```
UPDATE t
  SET t.image_column = s.image_column
  FROM dbo.table AS t
  INNER JOIN dbo.table AS s
  ON t.key = something
  AND s.key = something_else;
```

Sample:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(x INT PRIMARY KEY, i IMAGE);

INSERT @x SELECT 1,0x0045;
INSERT @x SELECT 2,0x0055;

UPDATE x SET x.i = y.i
  FROM @x AS x
  INNER JOIN @x AS y
  ON x.x = 1 AND y.x = 2;

SELECT x,i FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
x   i
--- ------
1   0x0055
2   0x0055
```